# Packaging is missing in the Project Properties in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build, ide

I wanted to build a jar from a project I just finished. I searched on google how to build a jar with NetBeans and in every source it says that I have to click under "Build" in the Project Properties on Packaging. As you can see on the screenshot "Packaging" is missing and I wanted to know if I just forgot something to do and if you know I can get to it.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Use `Run > Clean and Build Project` (or `Shift+F11`) to build the JAR file.

**Longer Answer:**

The options you see in the "Project Properties" menu will depend on how you created your Java project.

If you used `File > New Project > Java with Ant > Java Application...` then you will see the following options under Project Properties:

[image]

This shows you various settings to manage how the project is packaged.  But `Shift+F11` is how you can build the JAR. The output windows shows the following:

```
Building jar: C:\your\path\to\project\AntDemo\dist\AntDemo.jar
```

A lot of the NetBeans documentation that I have seen is fairly old, and it assumes you are using an Ant project (because that used to be the default project type).

If you used `File > New Project > Java with Maven > Java Application...` then you will see the following options under Project Properties:

[image]

This looks like your screenshot.

In this case, Maven is responsible for building the JAR - which is why the "Packaging" option is not visible in this case. If you want to customize how the JAR is built, you have to edit the related Maven `pom.xml` file that was created as part of your project.

But you can still use `Shift+F11` to initiate the build. The output will be different - something like this:

```
--- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MavenDemo ---
Building jar: C:\your\path\to\project\MavenDemo\target\MavenDemo-2.0.jar
```